# Converting int to hour(AM or PM) in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want convert int(number) to hour i.e., in AM or PM. i have variable a=17

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(a, "%H")
d.strftime("%I %p")
```

this is showing error as

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not int
```

if 17 is kept as "17" instead of a variable then its working properly. i am unable pass a variable to convert to hour. 
is there any alternative way for this ?

help me

Comment: "17" is a variable. why not `datetime.strptime(str(a), "%H")`?

Comment: a = 17 and a = “17” are both variables. The first represents an int while the 2nd represents a string. If it’s a = 17, you need to use str(a). If it’s a = “17”, you can just use a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try cast your `a` variable as a string rather than an integer either by setting it like:

```
a = str(17)
```

or:

```
datetime.strptime(str(a), "%H")
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty self explanatory

`argument 1 must be string, not int`

So you'll need to pass in a string.

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.strptime(str(a), "%H")
d.strftime("%I %p")
```